# Shared workbook hangs when opening and saving

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a shared Excel file with 14 people having access. The spreadsheet has been fine for a while, however, in the last 2 weeks, opening and saving the spreadsheet hangs for a good 4 to 5 minutes. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Shared excel sheets tend to grow to significant size as more and more revisions get put in. I've had success in shrinking them back to a manageable size by turning off shared edit mode and saving and then turning shared edit mode back on.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem with a macro here. I also have my sheets force macro use by hiding the sheets unless macros are enabled.

[How do you prevent corruption of shared Excel files?](https://superuser.com/questions/961918/how-do-you-prevent-corruption-of-shared-excel-files)